# reinstalled TexnicCenter/MikTex: "job aborted, file error in nonstop mode"

Tags: errors, pdf, texniccenter, miktex2.9

I've recently reinstalled TexnicCenter and Miktex for windows 10 (64).
However I'm having an issue getting the pdf to be produced. 
If anyone has some advice, I'd greatly appreciate it :)

The Build Output has the error

> pdflatex> ~ ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced

and the log has the error

> ! I can't write on file `test.pdf'.
>   Please type another file name for output
>   ! Emergency stop.
>   to be read again
>   \endgroup \set@typeset@protect 
>   l.11 \end{document}
>
> *** (job aborted, file error in nonstop mode)

My title is simply test.tex, and I've tried changing changing the name without success and also messing around with a few separate output profiles without success.

Thanks for any help!

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\section{test}
\end{document}
```

here is my log file:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (MiKTeX 2.9.7250 64-bit) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2019.11.17)  17 NOV 2019 05:34
entering extended mode
**./test.tex
(test.tex
LaTeX2e <2019-10-01> patch level 3
("C:\Users\John\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/base\article.cls"
Document Class: article 2019/10/25 v1.4k Standard LaTeX document class
("C:\Users\John\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/base\size10.clo"
File: size10.clo 2019/10/25 v1.4k Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count80
\c@section=\count81
\c@subsection=\count82
\c@subsubsection=\count83
\c@paragraph=\count84
\c@subparagraph=\count85
\c@figure=\count86
\c@table=\count87
\abovecaptionskip=\skip41
\belowcaptionskip=\skip42
\bibindent=\dimen102
)
(test.aux)
\openout1 = `test.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.

! I can't write on file `test.pdf'.
Please type another file name for output
! Emergency stop.
<to be read again> 
                   \endgroup \set@typeset@protect 
l.6 \end{document}

*** (job aborted, file error in nonstop mode)


Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 216 strings out of 492450
 2369 string characters out of 3120471
 61486 words of memory out of 3000000
 4665 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+200000
 4245 words of font info for 16 fonts, out of 3000000 for 9000
 1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 25i,4n,19p,125b,99s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,50000s
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

Comment: Seems like the .pdf is locked by the pdfviewer. Which do you use?

Comment: Oh? I haven't heard of that before.
Sumatra. I installed everything on default as per the most common instructions

Comment: So it's not the correct explanation, as Sumatra does not lock pdfs (contrary to Adobe Reader). Just in case: did you install MiKTeX first?

Comment: yes, MikTex, then Sumatra, then TexnicCenter.

Comment: Please show us the configuration for your used pdf viewer in TeXnicCenter, could be you have an error there ...